# Где можно найти открытую БД книг?

Tags: база-данных, книги, opensource, поиск-данных

Мне необходим каталог книг. Для каждой книги должно быть название и автор (минимум).
Не хотелось бы парсить labirint или ozon для такого, так как это не совсем честно по отношению к ним :)
Не могли бы вы подсказать открытый каталог для этих целей?

Comment: Если не сложно, добавьте в вопрос уточнение, книги на русском языке/английском?

Comment: Желательно на русском

Comment: Каждая книга имеет ISBN идентификатор, который регламентирован стандартом ISO 2108. Вам необходимо в поисках ориентироваться на эти данные. Лично я не знаю таких каталогов. Но по быстрому поиску вот: http://www.books-by-isbn.com/
В том числе и русские.

Comment: Хотелось бы с кнопкой "скачать". Так я и с labirint могу каталог скачать :)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: В целом ваш вопрос - оффтопик, т.к. сводится к поиску стороннего ресурса, а не к решению проблемы программирования или администрирования. Посмотрите в сторону http://isbndb.com/